# Multiple Checkboxes = Text in Text Box

Tags: vba, checkbox, excel-2016

I have a form I'm trying to build. I would like multiple checkboxs to ADD text to a textbox. I was unable to do to do that, without define alot! I used 3 Checkboxes in the original scenario. Now I have to do that using 12 checkboxes. I would like to know if there is an easier way to build this.

The fallowing shows what I used to with the original 3. I would really appreciate help so I don't have to do this for the next 12, it'd be A LOT! Thank you in advance!

---

```
Private Sub SUE_Click()

If SUE.value = True And SUD.value = False And SUG.value = False Then
    StartUp.Value = "E DEGD"
    
Else
If SUD.value = True And SUE.value = False And SUG.value = False Then
    StartUp.Value = "D DEGD"
   
Else
If SUG.value = True And SUD.value = False And SUE.value = False Then
    StartUp.Value = "G DEGD"
    
Else
If SUD.value And SUE.value And SUG.value = True Then
    StartUp.Value = "D DEGD, E DEGD, G ALT DEGD"

Else
If SUD.value And SUE.value = True Then
    StartUp.Value = "D DEGD, E DEGD"
  
Else
If SUE.value And SUG.value = True Then
    StartUp.Value = "E DEGD, G ALT DEGD"
    
Else
If SUD.value And SUG.value = True Then
    StartUp.Value = "D DEGD, G ALT DEGD"

Else
If SUE.value = False Then
    StartUp.Value = ""
    
Else
If SUD.value = False Then
    StartUp.Value = ""
    
Else
If SUG.value = False Then
    StartUp.Value = ""
    
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: what relation do the other 12 check boxes have to these 3, or to each other?

Comment: Its in a separate section, but basically I need the same result. The 3 original checkboxes is just how I made it work. I was wondering if there was an easier way. essential I want a text to be added to the text box when selected and when a second third..etc. checkbox is selected it will add to the textbox not replace the text.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think this is the way to go. You're going to end up with lots of lines of code each time you need to add a checkbox.

With the following, the only thing you need to do is :

1. Create your userform with all the checkboxes you need (keep track of the captions).
2. In the main, create as many stringprovider objects as you need (probably as many as there are checkboxes), supply them with the string they need to produce and the caption of the checkbox to which they are linked.
3. Register the stringproviders with the stringbuilder.
4. supply the stringbuilder to the form.

What you need to do is:

- Create a StringProvider class (you need to create a class module) as
  follows

This is a very simple class that contains 3 pieces of information:

1. The string you want to produce
2. The Enabled/Disabled state
3. The caption (case sensitive) of the checkbox to which it is linked.

This object is designed to store the string value you want as an output, e.g. "E DEGD", as well as the name (in fact the Caption) of the checkbox (e.g. "SUE", "SUD" in your code) that is linked to it.

```
    Option Explicit
    
    Private Type TValueProvider
        value As String
        IsEnabled As Boolean
        LinkledTB As String
    End Type
    
    Private this As TValueProvider
    
    Public Property Get value() As String
        value = this.value
    End Property
    
    Public Property Let value(v As String)
        this.value = v
    End Property
    
    Public Property Get IsEnabled() As Boolean
        IsEnabled = this.IsEnabled
    End Property
    
    Public Property Let IsEnabled(b As Boolean)
        this.IsEnabled = b
    End Property
    
    Public Property Get LinkedTB() As String
        LinkedTB = this.LinkledTB
    End Property
    
    Public Property Let LinkedTB(textboxname As String)
        this.LinkledTB = textboxname
    End Property
```

- A stringbuilder class, with the following code:
  This class will store all the stringprovider objects. When called, the UpdateString() sub will a) go through the registered stringproviders (in order of addition) and fire StringUpdated event that is used to inform the UserForm that the string was updated and that it needs to display it.

```
    Option Explicit
    
    Private Type TStringBuilder
        stringproviders As Collection
    End Type
    
    Public Event StringUpdated(newstring As String)
    
    Private this As TStringBuilder
    
    Private Sub class_initialize()
        Set this.stringproviders = New Collection
    End Sub
    
    Public Sub UpdateString()
        Dim k As Variant
        Dim sp As StringProvider
        Dim arr() As String
        Dim i As Long
        
        Dim EnabledStringProviders As Collection
        Set EnabledStringProviders = New Collection
        
        For Each k In this.stringproviders
            Set sp = k
            If sp.IsEnabled Then
                EnabledStringProviders.Add sp
            End If
        Next k
        
        If EnabledStringProviders.Count = 0 Then
            RaiseEvent StringUpdated(vbNullString)
        Else
            ReDim arr(EnabledStringProviders.Count - 1)
            
            For Each k In EnabledStringProviders
                Set sp = k
                arr(i) = sp.value
                i = i + 1
            Next k
            
            RaiseEvent StringUpdated(Join(arr, ", "))
            
        End If
     
    End Sub
    
    Public Sub RegisterStringProvider(sp As StringProvider)
        this.stringproviders.Add sp
    End Sub
    
    Public Function getSringProviderFromTBName(name As String)
        Dim sp As StringProvider
        Dim k As Variant
        
        For Each k In this.stringproviders
            Set sp = k
            If sp.LinkedTB = name Then
                Set getSringProviderFromTBName = sp
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next k
            
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, , "Could not find stringprovider with name: " & name
    End Function
```

This will hold a collection of stringproviders. When UpdateString() is called, it will go through the stringproviders and retrieve their value if they are updated.

- You also need wrapper for the checkbox object, which would look, like this:

```
    Option Explicit
    
    Private WithEvents WrappedTB As MSForms.CheckBox
    Private pstringbuilder As stringbuilder
    
    Public Sub Initialize(ByVal tb As MSForms.CheckBox, sb As stringbuilder)
        Set WrappedTB = tb
        Set pstringbuilder = sb
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub wrappedTB_Change()
        Dim sp As StringProvider
        Set sp = pstringbuilder.getSringProviderFromTBName(WrappedTB.Caption)
        
        sp.IsEnabled = WrappedTB.value
        
        pstringbuilder.UpdateString
    End Sub
```

The role of this wrapper is to capture the Checkbox_change event. Whenever a checkbox changes state, the wrappedTB_Change() sub is called. It requests the stringprovider linked to the checkbox from the stringbuilder and then calls the UpdateString method of the stringbuilder object. Note that stringbuilder holds references to the stringproviders so that an update to the stringprovider is automatically reflected inside the stringbuilder.

- Your form should look like this:

```
    Option Explicit
    
    Private WithEvents pstringbuilder As stringbuilder
    Private wrappers As Collection
    
    Private Sub UserForm_initialize()
        Set wrappers = New Collection
    End Sub
    
    Public Sub ShowDialog(sb As stringbuilder)
        Dim wrapper As ChkBoxWrapper
        Dim c As Control
        Set pstringbuilder = sb
        
        ' This code discovers how many checkboxes you have in the userform, and creates one
        ' wrapper per checkbox. It supplies each wrapper with the same stringbuilder object
        ' the wrappers are then stored in the wrappers collection.
        ' That way you don't need to know how many checkboxes there are at compile time.
        
        For Each c In Me.Controls
            Set wrapper = New ChkBoxWrapper
            If TypeName(c) = "CheckBox" Then
                wrapper.Initialize c, sb
                wrappers.Add wrapper
            End If
        Next c
        
        Me.Show
        
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub pstringbuilder_StringUpdated(s As String)
        ' This handles the event from the stringbuilder object.
        TextBox1.value = s
    End Sub
```

As an example usage, this is module1:

```
    Public Sub main()
    
    Dim frm As UserForm1
    Set frm = New UserForm1
    
    Dim sp1 As StringProvider
    Dim sp2 As StringProvider
    
    Set sp1 = StringProviderFactory("Toto", "CheckBox1") ' This is where you associate the string you want to output with the checkbox Caption
    Set sp2 = StringProviderFactory("Titi", "CheckBox2")
    
    Dim sb As stringbuilder
    Set sb = New stringbuilder
    
    ' Then you register each stringprovider with the stringbuilder. 
    sb.RegisterStringProvider sp1 
    sb.RegisterStringProvider sp2
    
    frm.ShowDialog sb
    
    
    
    End Sub
    
    
    Private Function StringProviderFactory(value As String, linked_TB_name As String) As StringProvider
    ' Just a helper function to create stringproviders
        Dim sp As StringProvider
        Set sp = New StringProvider
        sp.value = value
        sp.LinkedTB = linked_TB_name
        Set StringProviderFactory = sp
    End Function
```

I hope this helps. The code can be very much improved on, but hopefully this will get you started.